# Handling input change for API call in React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, httprequest

I am a newbie in React and in JavaScript in general, here I want to get the country result according to respective buttons (later updating the API URL accordingly). So far I managed to make the buttons work but surely this is not the correct way, since in the console I see that component is being called forever. So I would like to know what is the proper way of handling this situation

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      res: "",
      confirmedCases: 0,
      targetCountry: "",
      deathNumber: 0,
      targetProvince: "",
      userInput: "Azerbaijan"
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
    if (this.state.userInput !== prevState.userID) {

    fetch("https://covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/v1/stats?country="+this.state.userInput, {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "2f66132eeemsh16e2dd05b2ecd59p1ab765jsnc1f549cafc64",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com"
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
      this.setState({
        res: data.data.lastChecked,
        confirmedCases: data.data.covid19Stats[0].confirmed,
        targetCountry: data.data.covid19Stats[0].country,
        deathNumber: data.data.covid19Stats[0].deaths,
        targetProvince: data.data.covid19Stats[0].province
      })
      console.log(data.data.covid19Stats[0].confirmed)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
}

  handleChange = (target) =>{
    this.setState({
      userInput: target
    });
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <button onClick={(target) => this.handleChange("Azerbaijan", target)}>Azerbaijan</button>
       <button onClick={(target) => this.handleChange("Russia", target)}>Russia</button>
       <button onClick={(target) => this.handleChange("Turkey", target)}>Turkey</button>
      Last Updated:  {this.state.res}
        <br></br>
      Confirmed Cases:  {this.state.confirmedCases}
        <br></br>
      Country:  {this.state.targetCountry}
        <br></br>
      Number of Death:  {this.state.deathNumber}
        <br></br>
      Province:  {this.state.targetProvince}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just remove `componentDidUpdate` and add fetch API to handleChange function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `componentDidUpdate` and add fetch API to `handleChange` function.

Use `componentDidMount` for fetch default data.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      res: "",
      confirmedCases: 0,
      targetCountry: "",
      deathNumber: 0,
      targetProvince: "",
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleFetch("Azerbaijan");
  }

  handleChange = (target) => {
    this.handleFetch(target);
  };

  handleFetch = (target) => {
    fetch(
      "https://covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/v1/stats?country=" +
        target,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "x-rapidapi-key":
            "2f66132eeemsh16e2dd05b2ecd59p1ab765jsnc1f549cafc64",
          "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com",
        },
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          res: data.data.lastChecked,
          confirmedCases: data.data.covid19Stats[0].confirmed,
          targetCountry: data.data.covid19Stats[0].country,
          deathNumber: data.data.covid19Stats[0].deaths,
          targetProvince: data.data.covid19Stats[0].province,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.handleChange("Azerbaijan")}>
          Azerbaijan
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleChange("Russia")}>
          Russia
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleChange("Turkey")}>
          Turkey
        </button>
        <hr/>
        Last Updated: {this.state.res}
        <br/>
        Confirmed Cases: {this.state.confirmedCases}
        <br/>
        Country: {this.state.targetCountry}
        <br/>
        Number of Death: {this.state.deathNumber}
        <br/>
        Province: {this.state.targetProvince}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In handle change function you are giving target to userInput, it should be `target.target.value` well sounds weird so you might want change the former `target` to `event`

`event.target.value` is pretty common.

Also have a look at the hooks and function component, you can throw away most of the code here and replace it with same functionality but less code.

Levelup tutorials has good content, I'd recommend it.

Comment: I think you misunderstanding his question!